# Converting date to long in Java

Tags: java, arrays, date, type-conversion

I have the following string `02/11/2012 23:11`

Is there any way to convert this to the `long 021120122311l`?

I am trying to map objects to a specific position in an array based on their date created.

Comment: Note that a changed the title of this question. Representing a date as milliseconds-since-epoch requires a `long` primitive, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a SimpleDateFormat to generate it as a string without any symbol, and then parse the long value using the Long class

```
    SimpleDateFormat s1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat s2 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmm");
    Date d = s1.parse("02/11/2012 23:11");
    String s3 = s2.format(d);
    System.out.println(s3);
    long l = Long.parseLong(s3);
    System.out.println(l);
```

Comment: I think you want `HH` instead of `hh`.

Comment: This answer ignores the issue of time zone. This code works if all the date-time values are from the same time zone.

Comment: @BasilBourque that's true

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");

    Date inputDate;
    try {
        inputDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("02/11/2012 23:11");
        System.out.println(inputDate.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ouput:

```
1351878060000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
        String dateValue = "02/11/2012 23:11";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateValue);
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmm");
        String value = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        Long result = Long.parseLong(value);
        System.out.println("Result : "+result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Time zone is critical to parsing a string into a date-time value unless you absolutely sure all the strings represent date-times occurring in the same time zone.

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) makes this work much easier.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" );

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withZone( timeZone ).parseDateTime( myString );

long millisecondsSinceEpoch = dateTime.getMillis();
```